# Linux Mint File Manager Not Recognizing USB Drive After Formatting

Tags: linux-mint, filesystems, mount, disk

I reformatted a USB disk that I used to install Linux Mint 21 XFCE. After reformatting, the disk does not appear in Nemo or Nautilus. It does appear in the disks manager software, in `lsusb`, and in `sudo fdisk -l`.

I am not completely sure if the above confirms that the disk is mounted, but the disk manager lists it as /dev/sdb, and when I press the eject button in the disk manager some of the disk information blanks out. So I'm pretty sure it mounts.

I don't know how to access the drive via command line, but even if there is a way to do so, I vastly prefer to access it via the GUI.  .

Comment: Formatting is not enough. You need to make some filesystem.

Comment: Thank you @MC68020. I found a little plus sign in the disk utility that allowed me to create a file system. I'm now able to use the device normally. If you make this an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lsusb` lists the physical devices connected to your USB subsystem.
Storage devices being usually associated with a /dev/sd* device driver.

For standard use, Linux needs the physical device to be organized in some standard way : Filesystems. (ext2,3,4-zfs-btrfs…)

Regarding storage devices, Linux will only `mount` filesystems, these being commonly associated with the special files /dev/sdXN for the filesystems found on sdX device and N being a number starting from 1.

You therefore need to create at least one filesystem on your sdb device.
This being achievable thanks to the [mkfs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs) command line utility or via your graphical disk manager… but…
since you do not name it… I cannot help more. Your comment is however explicit, you managed to find your way clicking on the + sign, congrats!

Answer (score 0):

> I am not completely sure if the above confirms that the disk is mounted, but the disk manager lists it as /dev/sdb, and when I press the eject button in the disk manager some of the disk information blanks out. So I'm pretty sure it mounts.

That doesn't mean it's mounted – just that it's recognized as removable block device.

Checking whether it's mounted should be quite straightforward – check the output of `mount` for `/dev/sdb`.

If it's not mounted, run `dmesg -Hxw` and plug in your USB device – the kernel might tell you what goes wrong. If something goes wrong, chances are it's something like an "unclean file system", which you might be able to repair with `sudo fsck /dev/…`, depending on which file system you formatted the partition with.